# Can not show text labels on bars - d3js / javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I do not why my last part of text labels do not come up,  my coding as show as below:

```js
 var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 90 }
        var width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right
        var height = 2000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
        var svg = d3.select("#graph-1")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yushinglui/IV/main/c`enter code here`ourse_distance_v2.csv", function (data) {
    
    
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 60])
            .range([0, width]);
        
     svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
            .selectAll("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
            .style("text-anchor", "end");
    
      
        var y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, height])
            .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.CourseCode; }))
            .padding(0.1);
          
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    
      
        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
        
            .attr("x", function(d) { return 0 ; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.CourseCode); })
            .attr("width", function (d) { return x(d.AverageDistance); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y.bandwidth(); })
            .attr("fill", "#b3a269");
         
    
       svg.append('text')
         .attr('x', -(height / 2) )
         .attr('y', width - 410)
         .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
         .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
         .text('Course Code');
       
       svg.append('text')
         .attr('x', 150 )
         .attr('y', 1970)
         .attr('transform', 'rotate()')
         .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
         .text('Average Distance (Miles)');
       
         //text labels on bars -- not working!
          
        svg.selectAll("text")
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append("text")
         .text(function(d) { return d.AverageDistance; })
         
         .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.AverageDistance) + 15; })
         .attr("y", function (d) { console.log(d); return y(d.CourseCode) + y.bandwidth() * (0.5 + 0.1); })
        
        
         .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
         .attr("font-size", "12px")
         .attr("fill", "black")
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
    
        })
```

Comment: Please format your post appropriately using triple ` so the code is formatted. I tried to do it for you but most of the post is code so it needs to be cleaned up. In addition, more details are needed so others have proper context. For more info please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

2. Please remove any code that isn't necessary for reproducing the issue that you are trying to solve.

Comment: You already have text elements (axis, title, etc) so that when you use `selectAll('text')` when appending the labels, you are selecting existing elements. As these elements outnumber the number of items in the data array, the enter selection is empty. Try `selectAll(null).data(data).enter().append("text")`.